# Bootstrap - always hamburger menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with Bootstrap. When I check my code for example in codepen, the navbar is responsive, changes from visible links to hamburger menu, but if I check it in my document, it is always hamburger menu, no matter if it's big or small resolution. Can you help me? I am trying to solve it and I have no idea what is going on.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("img/bg.png");
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<html lang="pl">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light" id="commRollover">
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo" style="height: 40px;"></a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">O nas<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean with `it is always hamburger menu`? Of course the code will always be visible, it's the css that styles the menu to look good on any screen.

Comment: I mean there is always the toggle button, both mobile and desktop version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the "navbar-expand-lg" or "navbar-expand-md" etc classes to make the bootstrap 4 navbar only show the burger menu on smaller screens.

Here's the official bootstrap example.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#supported-content

And an example merged with your code.

```
<div class="container">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-expand-md navbar-light" id="commRollover">
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo" style="height: 40px;" ></a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">O nas<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
  </div>
```

Comment: And, to ALWAYS show the hamburger menu, you can omit the `navbar-expand-{sm, md, lg, xl, xxl}` altogether, at least that's true on BS5.